# SharePoint Framework Property Pane Choice Group options in an array

Tags: typescript, sharepoint

I am wanting to put a drop down list in the property pane:

```
PropertyPaneChoiceGroup('Marvels', { 
  label: "Marvels", 
  options: [ 
    { key: 'Hulk', text: 'Hulk' }, 
    { key: 'Thor', text: 'Thor' }, 
    { key: 'Captain America', text: 'Captain America' }, 
    { key: 'Ironman', text: 'Ironman' } ,
  ],
})
```

What I would like to do is to iterate over an array of names instead:

```
let marvelNames: string[] = ["Hulk", "Thor", "Cap", "Iron"];

PropertyPaneChoiceGroup('Marvels', { 
  label: "Marvels", 
  options: [ 
    for (let name in marvelNames) {
      { key: "name", text: "name" }
    }
  ],
})
```

I don't know how to achieve this.

I've only been working with JS/TS for a few weeks now and have much to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate the values as below:

```
let marvelNames: string[] = ["Hulk", "Thor", "Cap", "Iron"];

var characters: IPropertyPaneChoiceGroupOption[] = [];

marvelNames.map(function(item){
  characters.push({
    key:item,
    text: item
  })
});
```

After modify the property pane as:

```
PropertyPaneChoiceGroup('Marvels', { 
                  label: "Marvels",
                  options: characters                
})
```

Also, ensure that you have the correct import statement which includes `IPropertyPaneChoiceGroupOption` somewhat as:

```
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField,
  PropertyPaneChoiceGroup,
  IPropertyPaneChoiceGroupOption
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
```